# How to implement security profiles during installation of CentOS 8?

Tags: linux, centos, security

I am new to the Linux environment and I found CentOS to be a stable and secure operating system. I do not have much knowledge about the security profiles and how well do they protect the operating systems.

I saw many tutorials on YouTube in which everyone skipped the security profiles during installation of CentOS 8 while people installing CentOS 7 used to get an option to select security profiles ( information about it https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/C7SecurityProfiles).

The main question I would like to ask,

Q1. How do I implement security profiles in CentOS 8?

Q2. If we can't use the security profiles of CentOS 7 then what options do we have for CentOS 8?

Someone suggested me to use OpenSCAP (info about https://www.open-scap.org/security-policies/)

Q3. Will OpenSCAP keep the CentOS 8 secure?

Please provide some steps and suggestions which I could implement.

Answer (score 0):

- Install Fedora 31 (on a separate machine)
- Install `scap`
- Copy from fedora `/usr/share/xml/scap/ssg/content/ssg-centos8*` to your installed centos8 machine to `/usr/share/xml/scap/ssg/content/` folder (or download profiles from https://yadi.sk/d/zXGMa2wQv0mtuA)
- install `scap-workbench` and apply security policy with `scap-workbench` or apply policy by `oscap` without GUI

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do I understand you correctly that your solution requires installing Fedora on a separate computer in order to perform these steps? If not, please edit your answer to clarify step 1 of your list.